# Can't auto load the files in core directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, autoload

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. In the core directory of my app I have two files CMController.php and CMBase.php.

CMBase.php

```
class CMBase extends CI_Controller {}
```

CMController.php

```
CMController extends CMBase {}
```

Then in random controller

```
class RandomController extends CMController {}
```

And I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'CMBase' not found
```

subclass_prefix in the config is set to CM.
If I do require_once 'CMBase.php' in CMController file it works fine. 
So my question is why the file CMBase is not loaded automaticly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are extending the core controller your class name **needs to end with "Controller"**.  So you can't name your class `CMBase` it would have to be `CMBase_Controller`.

So if the value in `$config['subclass_prefix']` is "CM" you class needs to look like

```
class CMController extends CI_Controller {//...}
```

Then once you have done that you can do

```
class AnyClassName extends CMController {//...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_'; applications folder. Can only extend MY_Controller etc. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/MY-Controller

I think your missing the _ underscore part ie MY_

Comment: class CMBase extends CI_Controller {} try class "Your name" extends CMBase {} in core files see the way hmvc loads theres class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {}